# Is this $x \mapsto k^{k^{\frac{-1}{x}}}$ a contraction?

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces, fixed-point-theorems

Given that $k,x \in \mathbb{R}^+$ and $k > 1$, the function $f$ defined by $$f(x) = k^{k^{\frac{-1}{x}}}$$, generates a sequence $x_0,f(x_0), f(f(x_0)), \cdots$ is observed to converge to a fixed point independent of $x_0$. ([Proof](https://brilliant.org/wiki/soumavas-algorithm/#proof))

I was wondering if $f$ is a contraction on the metric space of $\mathbb{R}^+$ equipped with absolute distance.

Comment: Yes, given you exclude $0$ from the domain.

Comment: @fawningflagellum Can you help me prove it?

Answer (score 1):

If
$f(x) 
= k^{k^{\frac{-1}{x}}}
= e^{\ln(k)k^{\frac{-1}{x}}}
$,
so that

$\begin{array}\\
f'(x)
&=f(x)(\ln(k)k^{\frac{-1}{x}})'\\
&=f(x)(\ln(k)e^{\ln(k)\frac{-1}{x}})'\\
&=f(x)\ln(k)((\ln(k)\frac{-1}{x})'e^{\ln(k)\frac{-1}{x}})\\
&=f(x)\ln^2(k)\frac{1}{x^2}k^{\frac{-1}{x}}\\
&=\dfrac{k^{k^{\frac{-1}{x}}}\ln^2(k)k^{\frac{-1}{x}}}{x^2}\\
\end{array}
$

The condition
for a contraction mapping
is
$|f'(x)| < 1
$.
In this case,
The set of $x$
for which this is true
depends on numerical computation,
since it appears
highly unlikely
that an analytic solution
if possible.